# Not updating coordinate positions?

Tags: c++, opengl

I have managed to rotate a rectangle in OpenGL (C++) just fine. I am making a program that tests two rectangles for collision using the "separated axis theorem". To use the theorem, I need the x and y coordinates of each corner of the rectangle, but my problem is that, although I call `glRotatef(...)`, the coordinates of the corners of the rectangle are not changed to the values that they are rotated too, but the rectangle rotates as it should. How can I update the coordinates of my rectangle after glRotatef is called?

Code:

```
// float r1.x[4] and r1.y[4] hold the x and y position of each of the 4 corners, starting with the upper left (r1.x[0], r1.y[0])
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef((r1.x[0] + r1.x[2]) / 2, (r1.y[1] + r1.y[3]) / 2, 0); // Translates matrix to center of rectangle
    glRotatef(r1.angle, 0, 0, 1);
    glTranslatef(-((r1.x[0] + r1.x[2]) / 2), -((r1.y[1] + r1.y[3]) / 2), 0); // Translates back
    r1.angle++;

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glVertex2f(r1.x[0], r1.y[0]);
        glVertex2f(r1.x[1], r1.y[1]);
        glVertex2f(r1.x[2], r1.y[2]);
        glVertex2f(r1.x[3], r1.y[3]);
    glEnd();
```

Answer (score 2):

Transformation calls in OpenGL (like `glTranslatef` and `glRotatef`) update an internal transformation matrix that get multiplied by the points you provide before getting drawn on the screen. OpenGL does not at all touch your data.

In general, that is what you want. You have a model that is constant in time, but it gets transformed around.

If however, you do need to update your data, you need to create your own transformation matrix, manually multiply it and then draw with a clean transformation matrix (with `glLoadIdentity`)

You *could* get a little help from OpenGL though, as you can get the transformation matrix from OpenGL, but I don't recommend this. The math is not that hard and you'd appreciate learning how to do it.